# How to enable gzip in AWS EC2 Server for spring boot project?

Tags: .htaccess, spring-boot, compression, gzip, amazon-ec2

I have already edited **.htaccess** file in server and implemented server.compression in jar as below.
Even though its working in local-machine its not working in AWS EC2 instance,I have also made changes in **.htaccess** file also but no compression.

i have included following in    ***application.properties***

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=100
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/css,application/json
```

Can any one guide me to fix it.
or any other way to compress response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` is is file that is used to configure access for [Apache Web Server](https://httpd.apache.org/). Spring Boot runs on servlet container, which can be [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/).

Apache Web Server != Apache Tomcat

So changes to `.htaccess` file doesn't affect Spring Boot on your local machine nor on EC2.

Comment: thank you for your answer , changing .htaccess file is not required on local machine and its running but  can you plz help me how we can enable gzip on server AWS EC2 since it does't use Apache Web Server we cant do anything related to it .

Comment: Spring Boot configuration option you outlined should do the trick. But it relies also on deployment type. Is EC2 deployment hosted on embedded or shared Tomcat?

Comment: its embedded Tomcat.